# Using NavigationDrawer and setting ListFragment as root view

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, view

I have a NavigationDrawer and when onItemClick I want to put a **ListFragment** as the base view as shown in the bottom code!

However, the compiler returns an error saying I should change fragment's class to HomeworkListFragment.

When I do this, I get a second error saying at the .replace line saying that fragment's class should be Fragment.

This cycle continues on and I can't seem to solve it.

HomewokListFragment subclasses from ListFragment. but somehow this seems to be incompatible with inflating it into as the root view?

```
// Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
            Fragment fragment = new HomeworkListFragment(); // this fragment contains the list with all the "test" items

            // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                           .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                           .commit();

            // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

Comment: Have you tried `HomeworkListFragment fragment= new HomeworkListFragment()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the Support Library? If so you need to use getSupportFragmentManager() instead.

Comment: I was using the support library and that turned out to be my issue. Thanks for the tip!